# What does "$CP" mean in this java commandline?

Tags: java, command-line

I am learning java commandline and I see a commandline like this:

```
javac -classpath $CP *.java
```

So what does "$CP" mean in this commandline?

Comment: Note that `$CP` has nothing to do with Java.  This is the basic variable substitution syntax of the command line shell.  `$CP` can be used in any command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$CP` refers to a UNIX environment variable. Something like this:

`export CP=x.jar:y.jar:z.jar`

Comment: I think it is environment variable at first, but when I type "echo $CP", nothing happens and this command does execute well without any warnings or errors.

Comment: @Zhao if $CP is empty, there is no classpath.